# why would the tensorflow Poisson distribution return a float?

Tags: tensorflow, floating-point, poisson

I am using tensorflow Poisson distribution, and it seems to be returning the dtype float32. That makes no sense. Am I mistaken?

Comment: What does not make sense exactly? Are you talking about `Poisson.prob` receiving a float instead of an integer, for example?

Comment: I am talking about poisson.sample(). this distribution normally deals with discrete events. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution